# How to fit a skewed normal to the data and obtain the corresponding parameters?

Tags: fitting, distributions

I have:

```
data = {0.00677966, 0.0677966, 0.335593, 0.308475, 0.213559, 0.0440678, 0.0237288}
```

Although, the normal fit to the data is not bad:

```
FindFit[data, a PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x], {a, \[Mu], \[Sigma]}, x]

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[1.0039315962152484` PDF[NormalDistribution[3.7375634392795765`, 1.1189958022789113`], x], {x, 1, 7}], PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

how can I fit a skewed normal with its max (peak) happening at the maximum value of the dataset at $x = 3$?

Comment: What did you get when you used `SkewNormalDistribution` instead of `NormalDistribution`?  And to state the obvious:  fitting 5 parameters (a, $\mu$, $\sigma$,  skew normal parameter $\alpha$, and the error variance is living dangerously with only 7 data points.  Finally, do you "know" that the maximum occurs at $x=3$?  Or did you mean that the maximum values should be near $x=3$?

Comment: My suggestion is actually not to perform a fit at all given the limited amount of data.  Short of that you should attempt to find confidence intervals for the curve which might be so wide as to suggest that the fit is not very good.  If you really know that the peak is at 3, then in essence that would mean that there's one less parameter to estimate.  I'll write something that will account for that.

Comment: Sorry, after finding that the mode does not have a closed-form, it looks too messy to include that restriction (at least for the time I would have available to do so).  Someone else might be interested.  And I have to ask:  What you're doing is fitting a curve that just happens to be a multiple of a probability density function.  There's no relationship to obtaining samples from a skew normal distribution.  I find it hard to believe that there's some theoretical attachment to a skew normal distribution.  (The mode of a curve being 3 I can believe. It's the curve form that I'm skeptical about.)

Comment: About your 7 data points:  upon further inspection of your data it appears that you had a sample size of 295 and binned the data in to 7 categories.  Do you not have the raw data?  If true, then a regression is a horrible/inappropriate way to estimate the parameters of a random sample from a distribution.  If my inference about your data correct, please update your question with how the data was constructed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having sufficient data to use the methods discussed in the question

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment on your data.  The sum of the data values is exactly 1 which suggests that the values are relative frequencies of raw data that was binned into 7 categories.  If so, then the minimum sample size can be determined if those frequencies are (near) exact integers if multiplied by an appropriate integer sample size.

If the minimum relative frequency happens to be 2, then dividing by that relative frequency times 2 results (essentially) in all integers:

```
data = {0.00677966, 0.0677966, 0.335593, 0.308475, 0.213559, 0.0440678, 0.0237288}
data/(data[[1]]/2)
(* {2., 20., 98.9999, 91.0001, 62.9999, 13., 7.} *)
```

So my inference is that the sample sizes in the bins are

```
{2, 20, 99, 91, 63, 13, 7}
```

If this is the case, then you don't want to perform a regression with `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`.  (Yes, you could get initial estimate of the parameters because `a` is approximate 1 but you cannot obtain appropriate estimates of precision for any of the parameter estimates because the true sample size is ignored.)

One should use the raw data (295 data points) or the counts (not relative frequencies) with the bin dimensions.

If the above scenario is true, please update your question with that information.  Also if true, this is a common issue on this site:  inappropriately using regression to estimate parameters from samples from a probability distribution.

**Continuation...**

From the OP's comments, the frequency counts of the 7 bins are

```
counts = {2, 20, 99, 91, 63, 13, 7};
```

The log of the likelihood using those counts is constructed as follows:

```
logL = Sum[counts[[i]] Log[CDF[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α], i + 1/2] -
  CDF[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α], i - 1/2]], {i, 1, 7}];
```

Find the maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters:

```
mle = FindMaximum[{logL, σ > 0}, {{μ, 3}, {σ, 1}, {α, 2}}]
(* {-447.496, {μ -> 2.73095, σ -> 1.58046, α -> 2.21325}} *)
```

Plot the results:

```
Show[Plot[PDF[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α] /. mle[[2]], x], {x, 0, 8}], 
  ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[7], counts/Total[counts]}]]]
```

[image: Frequency counts and fit]

Standard errors associated with the parameter estimates can be estimated:

```
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{μ, σ, α}, 2}]) /. mle[[2]]];
sd = Sqrt[Diagonal[cov]]
(* {0.141689, 0.123186, 0.584415} *)
```

The mode can be estimated numerically or with an approximation:

*Numerical estimation:*

```
m = FindMaximum[PDF[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α] /. mle[[2]], x], x]
(* {0.385924, {x -> 3.55297}} *)
```

*Approximation* (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution

```
δ = α/Sqrt[1 + α^2];
μz = δ Sqrt[2/π];
σz = Sqrt[1 - μz];
γ1 = ((4 - π)/2) (δ Sqrt[2/π])^3/(1 - 2 δ^2/π)^(3/2);
m0 = μz - γ1 σz/2 - (1/2) Exp[-2 π/α];
mode = μ + σ m0 // FullSimplify;
mode /. mle[[2]]
(* 3.6234 *)
```

I've assumed (maybe inappropriately) that the true $\alpha$ is positive.  That allows me to use the Delta Method to estimate the standard error for the estimate of the mode:

```
Sqrt[(D[mode, {{μ, σ, α}, 1}].cov.D[mode, {{μ, σ, α}, 1}]) /. mle[[2]]]
(* 0.115903 *)
```

I'm not convinced that the mode should be forced to be 3 which seems to come from the fact that the highest binned frequency happens to be 3.  (Other binning or using the raw data might likely result in a value much closer the estimates of the mode found above.)

Comment: I've had practice at that specific issue more than I can count on this site.  So are the bins 0.5 to 1.5, 1.5 to 2.5, etc.?\

Comment: The raw data would be better but it is still doable with the counts (and bin borders).

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

The nature of the functions requires use of moderately high arbitrary precision rather than machine precision.

```
wp = 20; (* WorkingPrecision *)

data = SetPrecision[{0.00677966, 0.0677966, 0.335593, 0.308475, 0.213559, 
    0.0440678, 0.0237288}, wp];
```

Use a [`NormalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html) to get an initial estimate for most of the parameters to be used in the [`SkewNormalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SkewNormalDistribution.html).

```
(p = (nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[data,
       {a*PDF[NormalDistribution[m, s], x], a > 0, s > 0}, {a, m, s}, x,
       WorkingPrecision -> wp])[
    "BestFitParameters"]) // N

(* {a -> 1.00393, m -> 3.73756, s -> 1.119} *)

f[a_, b_, m_, s_, x_] = a*PDF[SkewNormalDistribution[m, s, b], x];
```

To constrain the peak to `x == 3`, requires

```
cons = Simplify[(D[f[a, b, m, s, x], x] /. x -> 3) == 0, {s > 0, a > 0}]

(* 2 b s + E^((b^2 (-3 + m)^2)/(2 s^2)) (-3 + m) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
    Erfc[(b (-3 + m))/(Sqrt[2] s)] == 0 *)

(nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data,
     {f[a, b, m, s, x], cons, a > 0, s > 0},
     {{a, a /. p}, b, {m, m /. p}, {s, s /. p}}, x,
     WorkingPrecision -> wp]) // Normal // Quiet

(* 0.19431020606331336534 E^(-0.10999792906276025428 (-2.3156921525194094080 + 
    x)^2) Erfc[-2.1124424482559999546 (-2.3156921525194094080 + x)] *)

Show[
 Plot[{nlm1[x], nlm2[x]}, {x, 1, Length[data]},
  PlotLegends ->
   Placed[{"normal", "skewnormal"}, {.8, .8}]],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]